# Write a function with 2 arguments (string and integer) and it should print out a square of characters as I wrote in description field

Tags: python, function, arguments

Here is my function, but it doesn't properly work. The 1st output line is fine, but the 2nd line starts text from beginning instead of continuing it. :

```
def squared(text, length):
    for i in range(length):
        if i%length==0: 
            result=text*length
        
        print(result[0:length])
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    squared("abc", 5)
```

The out put must be:

```
abcab
cabca
bcabc
abcab
cabca
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `cycle` around the text and for each line `islice` the next 5. That way you don't have to manage any indices and mod math.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def squared(text, length):
    letters = cycle(text)  # lazy iterator -> abcabcabcabc....
    for i in range(length):
        print("".join(islice(letters, length)))
        # print(*islice(letters, length), sep="")

>>> squared("abc", 5)
abcab
cabca
bcabc
abcab
cabca
```

**Some docs**

- [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)
- [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't go that far with my Python course yet and didn't know what is itertools.cycle.

Comment: You should definitely try to make the manual approach with `%` work. That is important training for a beginner. You will get to know the toolbox soon enough :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 def squared(text, times):
    sent1=""
    sent2=""
    turns=1
    while turns<=times:
     sent1+=text*times
     print(sent1[0:times])
     sent2=sent1[times:]
     sent1=sent2
     turns+=1


    if __name__ =="__main__":
        squared("abcde", 4)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].